# Ways to consume Linux and open-source related news on Android device?

Tags: rss

I would like to read Linux and open-source related news from my Android device. My current solution is a *gReader Pro*, which supports 4x4 widget and I have configured it to display RSS feeds from multiple sources:

[image: gReader]

The problem is, that often those RSS feeds show only the title or short summary and one still needs to visit the web page to read the whole article. Is there a way around this or only solution is to use RSS sources which publish full articles as RSS? In addition, I tried with few "personal magazin" apps like *Flipboard*, but I still ended up at the news-source web-page.

Comment: In gReader, double tap on the opened article, article(summary) will convert to full article automagically. No Need To visit Web page of article. I use this feature a lot and love it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Pocket](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ideashower.readitlater.pro&hl=en) or [Readability](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.readability&hl=en). They are both Android apps that parse HTML into more readable formats without having to visit the site.